# Change path of uploaded file based upon content type using Paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I am using Paperclip to handle file uploads for my application. I need to be able to change the path of the file based upon the `content-type` of the file. When I attempt to do this with a lambda I am receiving a `stack level too deep` error.

```
has_attached_file :file, :storage => :s3,
                          path: lambda { |a| a.instance.determine_path_for_content },
                          :s3_credentials => { 
                          :bucket => 'myBucket', 
                          :access_key_id => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY'],
                          :secret_access_key => ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
                          }

def determine_path_for_content
    if file.instance.file_content_type == "video/mp4"
        "/:name/:event:event_id/:basename_time_:start_mp4_at_end_time:fingerprint.:extension"
    else
        "/:name/:event:event_id/:basename_:fingerprint.:extension"
    end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:

```
has_attached_file :file, :storage => :s3,
                          path: lambda { |a| a.class.determine_path_for_content(file.instance.file_content_type) },
                          :s3_credentials => { 
                          :bucket => 'myBucket', 
                          :access_key_id => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY'],
                          :secret_access_key => ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
                          }

def self.determine_path_for_content(content_type)
    if content_type == "video/mp4"
        "/:name/:event:event_id/:basename_time_:start_mp4_at_end_time:fingerprint.:extension"
    else
        "/:name/:event:event_id/:basename_:fingerprint.:extension"
    end
end
```

It is, in my view, better to have this as a class method and that should avoid the recursion you have here.